# Magento 2 : Newsletter Subscription Discount

Tags: magento2, newsletter

I would like to implement something like,

**If Customer/Visitor subscribe to newsletter than he will get discount worth 5.**

How can i achieve this ? Need some guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a new customer group. When anyone subscribes newsletter than you need to add particular email address customer to this group

Create a cart price rule for created customer group

set  Uses per Customer to 1 so anyone can able to use that discount for only once.
give fixed amount discount of 5 in this rule

Comment: Great , I will try it let you know.